# Delaying advert loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, ads

We run a reasonably large website, funded through advertising.

In order to keep our users happy and maintain a good browsing experience, we employed some javascript that loads adverts at the bottom of the page and then moves them into position later. Here is the code we place just before the closing of the  tag:

```
<div id="topadloader" style="display:block;"><!--adcode here--></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var loader = document.getElementById('topadloader');
    document.getElementById("topad").appendChild(loader);
    </script>
```

We then just place an empty div where we want the advert to be displayed:

```
<div id="topad"></div>
```

This is all well and good, except that occasionally some of our adverts use iframes to position bits of text etc. These iframes are broken by the above code, resulting in our adzones displaying blank ads.

I was wondering if there was anything we could do to fix the issue, so that iframes work as normal?

Comment: There is generally no problem moving iframes in the manner you are doing so you'd have to show us more of the troublesome HTML for us to be able to help.

Comment: It's quite hard to provide more, since there is little more I can actually provide. For example, one advert tries to load an iframe with <iframe width="160" scrolling="no" height="600" frameborder="no" framespacing="0"></iframe>, but the the actual content of the iframe is blank. It is just a set of empty html and body tags. Let me know if there is anything specific I can provide and will do so.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a smaller jsFiddle then?  There is no generic problem with moving an iframe to a new location in the DOM so whatever is causing your problem is related to something you have not disclosed to us.  Not much else we can do if you don't provide more info.

Comment: It's very odd. I tried it out on a blank page (http://stage.p2.pe/html/) and it is working fine. But on the site in question (http://www.oneddl.eu), the iframes don't get moved properly.

Answer (score -1):

I have a stupid idea, maybe you should try using a redirect code?

I mean like doing a redirect code inside an iframe this is the most strangest idea have ever come up with but if you think about it.... it could work!! :P